# How to monitor accuracy with CTC loss function and Datasets? (runnable code included)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been trying to speed up training of my CRNN network for optical character recognition, but I can't get the accuracy metric working when using TFRecords and `tf.data.Dataset` pipelines. I previously used a Keras Sequence and had it working. Here is a complete runnable toy example showing my problem (tested with Tensorflow 2.4.1):

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Layer, Bidirectional, GRU, Reshape, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
CHAR_VECTOR = "ABC"
IMG_W = 10
IMG_H = 10
N_CHANNELS = 3


class CTCLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = K.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred, label_length):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # At test time, just return the computed predictions
        return y_pred


def get_model():
    n_classes = len(CHAR_VECTOR) + 1

    input = Input(name='image', shape=(IMG_W, IMG_H, N_CHANNELS), dtype='float32')
    label = Input(name='label', shape=[None], dtype='float32')
    label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[None], dtype='int64')

    x = Reshape(target_shape=(IMG_W, np.prod(input.shape[2:])), name='reshape')(input)
    x = Dense(24, activation='relu', name='dense1')(x)
    x = Bidirectional(GRU(24, return_sequences=True, name="GRU"), merge_mode="sum")(x)
    x = Dense(n_classes, name='dense2')(x)
    y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(x)

    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc")(label, y_pred, label_length)

    m = Model(inputs=[input, label, label_length], outputs=output)
    return m


def image_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[tf.io.encode_jpeg(value).numpy()]))


def float_feature_list(value):
    """Returns a list of float_list from a float / double."""
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))


def int64_feature(value):
    """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def create_example(image, label, label_length):
    feature = {
        "image": image_feature(image),
        "label": float_feature_list(label),
        "label_length": int64_feature(label_length),
    }
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))


def parse_tfrecord_fn(example):
    feature_description = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "label": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "label_length": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
    example["image"] = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(tf.io.decode_jpeg(example["image"], channels=3), dtype="float32")
    example["label"] = tf.sparse.to_dense(example["label"])

    return example


def generate_tfrecords(n):
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(filename) as writer:
        for i in range(n):
            random_img = np.random.random((IMG_W, IMG_H, N_CHANNELS))
            label_length = random.randint(1, max_text_len)
            label = np.random.randint(0, len(CHAR_VECTOR), max_text_len)
            example = create_example(random_img, label, label_length)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())


class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __len__(self):
        return steps_per_epoch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        outputs = np.zeros([batch_size])
        dataset = get_dataset()
        inputs = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
        return inputs, outputs


def get_dataset():
    generate_tfrecords(batch_size * epochs * steps_per_epoch)
    dataset = (
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
        .map(parse_tfrecord_fn, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
    return dataset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    batch_size = 9
    epochs = 7
    steps_per_epoch = 8
    max_text_len = 5
    filename = "test.tfrec"
    use_generator = False
    data = DataGenerator() if use_generator else get_dataset()

    model = get_model()
    '''This fails when use_generator == False, removing the 
     metric solves it'''
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.fit(data, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)
```

Set `use_generator = False` or remove `metrics=["accuracy"]` and it will run without error.

As you can see the `DataGenerator` uses the same data from the TFRecords, but it also returns some zeros, and for whatever reason this seems to be the magic sauce:

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __len__(self):
        return steps_per_epoch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        outputs = np.zeros([batch_size])
        dataset = get_dataset()
        inputs = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
        return inputs, outputs
```

I also noticed that this Keras example suffers from the same problem (it crashes if you edit the code to monitor accuracy): https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/

Is there any way to mimic the behaviour of `__getitem__` with the `Dataset`, or some other way of getting the accuracy without using a `Sequence`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the dataset for training you need to include the outputs. Your generator function returns (correctly) a tuple (inputs, outputs); When you pass the dataset directly that is missing.

If you modify the mapper function as such:

```
def parse_tfrecord_fn(example):
    feature_description = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "label": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "label_length": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
    }
    tf_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_description)
    tf_example["image"] = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf_example["image"], channels=3), dtype="float32")
    tf_example["label"] = tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_example["label"])

    return tf_example, tf.constant([0])
```

The code will now run without errors with use_generator = False. Note that accuracy as a metric doesn't make sense. The metric compares the output of the network (y_pred) with the target (tf.constant([0]). In order to measure accuracy you need to feed the label as the target... and you need a function that can compare the output of your network which is of the shape (batch_size, max_sequence_lenght, n_classes) with the labels. i.e. you need a sparse categorical accuracy metric.

You can find my notebook at:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z2NCQnYlG_UIpN7bBNpXXbLwy3JE_PX2?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you a lot for your insightful answer! It helped me towards a solution, have bounty!

I'm aware that tracking accuracy doesn't really make sense, but I have had it working, albeit with a slightly different implementation that called the ctc_batch_cost function in a Lambda layer. It's still a mystery to me how that ever worked.

In fact your suggestion of using sparse categorical accuracy doesn't work either as the prediction tensor isn't one-hot encoded. I ended up writing a custom metric function. I have submitted a pull request of my solution to the Keras captcha_ocr example.

Answer (score 1):

There probably [some issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22190) with `[accuracy]` with `tf.data`, but I'm not super sure if this is the main cause in your case or if the issue still exits. If I try as follows, it runs anyway without `Sequence` (with `tf.data`).

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

Comment: While your suggestion does allow it to run, it does not produce an actual accuracy. I realise that this is hard to tell from my little example, as I used random images, but it can easily be seen in the Keras example: https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/
Just open it in Colab and edit in the metric and you'll see.

I've decided to stick to using a Sequence for now, unless I stumble across a solution.